# How to plot the histogram of image width in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, ipython, opencv

I have some training images (more than 20 image with format .tif)that i want to plot their  histogram of width in python. I will be more than happy if any one can helps.

Answer (score 1):

ok i will give you the steps, but the coding has to be done by you
assuming you have python installed and pip in you machine

1. Install pillow using pip
2. get the images in the script and calculate the width and store them in a list, you will get to know how to calculate width from the Pillow documentation
3. Install matplotlib using pip
4. Pass that list you created from the images to the plotting function of matplotlib.
5. the Histogram representation can be found in Matlpoltlib documentation

hope it helps,

Comment: Note that Pillow is not necessary for that. You can read images and access their widths with plain `scipy.misc.imread`, although you still need to have `scipy` installed (but you are more likely to already have it than Pillow...)

Comment: yeah bro, any one package is needed. i just said pillow, even scipy can be used. anyways thanks bro

Comment: @Exprator Thanks for your comment.